# How to disable the back button on a pushed page?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my page i use this:

```
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
```

[Automatically generated back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMZuS.png)

but a back button will automatically be added to the pushed view, how to use default bar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to have the back button then you can set it as a root page using "setRoot()" instead of push() like this,

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the Back button to be shown as an option you could simply hide it on the page in which you are navigating to.

`<ion-navbar hideBackButton="true"></ion-navbar>`

More info on Ionic NavBar [here.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Navbar/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, in case you want to be able to go back to a previous page without having to load it again..

Answer (score -1):

just try this it work great for me it will be automatically deactivate back button and show Menu toggle

```
this.childNavCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
```